# Exclude data from brackets using regex (preg_match_all)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Input string:

```
:txt{sometext}:alpha
```

I want to extract data like this (extracted from brackets):

Result using `preg_match_all()`:

```
sometext
```

Trying like this, but none of this works:

```
php >  preg_match_all('/^(\:txt)(.*)+(\{)(.*)+(\})/i', ':txt{sometext}:alpha', $m); var_dump($m);
array(6) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(14) ":txt{sometext}"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) ":"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [3] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "{"
  }
  [4] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [5] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(1) "}"
  }
}
```

Note: as sample I have like this `:txt{sometext}:alpha:another{mydata}`, so I can extract data from `:another` and give results like `mydata`.

RESULTS:

Result from Sniffer:

```
php >  preg_match_all('/(?<=:txt{)([^}]+)(?=})/', ':txt{sometext}:alpha', $x); var_dump($x);
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "sometext"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "sometext"
  }
}
```

Result from Jerry:

```
php >  preg_match_all('/^:txt\{([^}]+)\}/', ':txt{sometext}:alpha', $x); var_dump($x);
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(14) ":txt{sometext}"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(8) "sometext"
  }
}
```

Comment: Same result. Must be with `:txt` before brackets. So, before finding brackets should find if exists `:txt`.

Comment: Oops, misunderstood question.

Comment: Fixed. Yes, i'm sorry.

Comment: The results are like that because the function returns the whole thing that matched plus whatever is inside capturing groups, in my case if you only want what was matched then remove the capturing group parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why all this, why not just:

```
(?<=:txt{)([^}]+)(?=})
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qL6iL7)

Comment: No. Must start with `:txt` because in another situation i have `:something`.

Comment: Working, but in `preg_match_all()` should be `/(?<=:txt{)([^}]+)(?=})/`

Comment: @MarinSagovac I didn't delimit the pattern, but it is working right ?

Comment: Your solution WORKS! It's returned for BOTH results and more units. Thank you. SOLVED.

Comment: Delimit pattern must be in PHP to work. Otherwise, not working.

Comment: @MarinSagovac I know :). Anyway thank you for accepting and glad I could help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37123/discussion-between-marin-sagovac-and-sniffer)